# get local notification From Json URL

Tags: angular, notifications, ionic4

l have ionic app for flights schedules details using data json api .l want to make when user click on bell he will get notification about the status of flight , if she is arrival or delay or landed . l installed [Local Notifications
 native](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/local-notifications/)  for ionic .

[image]

`home.ts` holding data json url

```
  constructor(private http: HTTP, private localNotifications: LocalNotifications) {

 this.getdata()
   }


    async getdata() {

     const loading = await this.loadingController.create({
       message: 'Loading'
     });
     await loading.present();

      this.http.get('/airport.json?code=bs', {}, {})
      .then(data => {

         this.test = JSON.parse(data.data);
         const parsed = JSON.parse(data.data);
        this.yestrday = parsed.result.response.airport.pluginData.schedule.arrivals.data;
         loading.dismiss()



       }), err=>{
         this.test =err
        loading.dismiss()
     } 

 }
 navigate(item,aiprot,time,type,status,airline,logo){
this.nav.navigateForward(`/flightserachdetails/${item}/${aiprot}/${time}/${type}/${status}/${airline}/${logo}`);
 }
 }
```

page holding data for flight details

```
    export class FlightserachdetailsPage {

      public flight : any

      callsign =null
      airport = null 
      status = null
      aircraft = null
      airline = null
      time = null
      logo = null
      constructor(private http: HTTP, public loadingController: LoadingController,private localNotifications: LocalNotifications,
                   private nav : NavController,private activatedRoute : ActivatedRoute) {
                    this.activatedRoute.params.subscribe((params) => {
                      this.callsign = params['callsign'];
                      this.airport = params['airport'];
                      this.time = params['time'];
                      this.aircraft = params['aircraft'];
                      this.status = params['status'];
                      this.airline = params['airline'];
                      this.logo = params['logo'];



                    });

       }

   AlertFlight(){
    if (this.status=='Landed') {
      this.localNotifications.schedule({
        title: 'My first notification',
        text: 'flight is landed',
        foreground: true

      });
    }
  }
    }
```

html

```
<button item-right clear (click)="AlertFlight()">
```

Comment: You need to use an observable and push the change in value so that any variable subscribed can get notified and update

Comment: could you please do it for me ? or give me example ? l am beginner .

Answer (score 0):

The condition you are checking in the AlertFlight() method is `this.status=='landed'` but the status you are showing in the image is '**Landed**'.so change the condition like this

```
   AlertFlight(){
    if (this.status=='Landed') {
      this.localNotifications.schedule({
        title: 'My first notification',
        text: 'flight is landed',
        foreground: true

      });
    }
  }
```

Comment: l did that , he is working only when Landed status is live ! . l want him to reaming check for while when status become is Landed he will going to send notification automatic to advice this flight is Landed

Answer (score 0):

Here is an example in plain js, it works the same way in angular.

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <script src="https://npmcdn.com/@reactivex/rxjs@5.0.0-beta.7/dist/global/Rx.umd.js"></script>
    <script>
      let subject = new Rx.Subject();
      let status = "";
      Rx.Observable.of("").subscribe(x => {
        setTimeout(() => {
          status = "departed";
          subject.next("status");
        }, 1000),
          setTimeout(() => {
            status = "enroute";
            subject.next(status);
          }, 10000),
          setTimeout(() => {
            status = "landed";
            subject.next(status);
          }, 10000);
      });

      subject.subscribe(x => {
        AlertFlight();
      });
      function AlertFlight() {
        if (status == "landed") {
          console.log("landed alert");
        }
      }
    </script>
    <title>Page Title</title>
  </head>
  <body></body>
</html>
```

Comment: thank you brother for answer . l updated my question code . where should l put your code ? with home.ts or flight details code ? see my update question . thank you